# Flutter ellipsis broken when using a custom font

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have an issue. I am using the Oxygen font from Google Fonts (Oxygen-Regular.ttf) and when I use:

```
                  child: Text( 
                              item.name, 
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              softWrap: false,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            ),
```

The display of ellipsis gets really weird, a small square appears:

[image]

Whereas when I use the default font of the flutter app, ... three dots appear, as I want. So, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try with any other `ttf`?

Comment: I downloaded the font and experimented and the problem you talked about did not appear

Comment: I have tried and its working fine. I guess you should wrap this text widget with container.

Comment: Yes, other `ttf` works, but `oxygen` fails. Wrapping in container gives the same result

Comment: This is (at the meantime) a known issue at Flutter and is tracked here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58626
As of now, there is no solution, however there the issue only occurs when you change font family and font size or weight.